# SQL table not showing inserted data after trigger creation

Tags: sql, triggers

I Have created a simple table and inserted some values into it. I then created an instead of trigger to stop anyone named 'John' from inserting a value and also anyone who have already answered the question.
My problem is that when I insert new values the query executes successfully but the table is not updated.

```
CREATE TABLE user_reponse(
    Username        VARCHAR(50),
    QuestionID      VARCHAR(10),
    Answer          CHAR(1)
    )

INSERT INTO user_reponse VALUES
('Tom', 'Q001', 'D'), ('Wendy', 'Q009', 'A'), ('Eddy', 'Q089', 'C'), ('David', 'Q001', 'C'), 
('Eve', 'Q001', 'D'), ('Paul', 'Q001', 'A'), ('Sam', 'Q001', 'B')


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_instead_of]
    ON [dbo].[user_reponse]
INSTEAD OF insert
AS
IF (SELECT Username FROM inserted) = 'John'
BEGIN
RAISERROR('You have not paid up your fee', 16, 1)
SELECT * FROM inserted
ROLLBACK
END
IF EXISTS(SELECT a.Username, b.Username FROM user_reponse a, inserted b WHERE a.Username = b.Username)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('You have already submitted this question', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK
END


INSERT INTO user_reponse VALUES
('John', 'Q001', 'D')
INSERT INTO user_reponse VALUES
('zzz', 'Q002', 'A')

SELECT * FROM user_reponse
```

Comment: use `After insert update`

Comment: Are you saying `sql` and you really mean Microsoft `sql-server` ?? Please update your tags to include the **actual, concrete database** that you're using - `sql` is just the query language, used by many RDBMS - but triggers are highly vendor-specific, so we need to know what concrete database system you're using

Comment: Solved - I needed to add an ELSE statment after the IF to insert the inserted row ELSE
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user_reponse 
   SELECT * FROM inserted
 END

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `INSTEAD OF`-trigger - so the trigger is executed instead of the insert which is ignored. I think you rather want a `BEFORE`-trigger to check values and maybe raise an error before the actual insert happens.